# Angular JS 1.6 help as a Service results in an UNK Provider when what I'm doing is perfectly correct

Tags: angularjs

So, I am doing VERY SIMPLE controller like I've done before on my personal website I made back 8 years ago.

What I'm facing is an enormous app with code that followed no coding standards.

Here's my controller, inside a controller.js file:

```
app.controller("documentController", ["$scope", "documentService", ($scope, documentService) => {

    let docCtrl = $scope;
    //docCtrl = 'Hello World!';
    docCtrl.docContent = [];
    console.log('DOC CONTROL: ', docCtrl.content);

    docCtrl.fetchDocs = function () {
      documentService.getDocuments().then(function (result) {
        docCtrl.docContent = result.data;
        console.log('DOCS RETRIEVED: ', docCtrl.docContent);
      });
    }
    docCtrl.fetchDocs();
}]);
```

and the service I need call inside a service.js file that's in the same module folder.

```
app.service('documentService', ["$http", "URL", ($http, URL) => {
    let getDocuments = function () {
        return $http.get(URL)
            .success(function (data) {
                console.log('SUCCESS: Documents retreived', data);
                return data;
            })
            .error(function (e) {
                console.log(`He's dead Jim!`, e);
                return e;
            })
    }
    return ({
        getDocunment: getDocuments
    });
}]);
```

Inside that controller.js file is a 2584 line controller set up the same way as my very simple controller that calls an 1000 line service in the service.js file.

My code sits at the bottom.

What happens is, when I run the app, I get UNK Provider error for the service.

Oh, I have a directive that also sits in the controller.js which is found and works.

```
app.directive("documentDirective", ["$compile", ($compile) => {
    let data = {};
    data.restrict = 'AE';
    data.link = async ($scope, $element) => {
        const template = '<span>Hello World!</span>'
        await $element.html('').append($compile(template)($scope));
    };
    return data;
}]);
```

So, when I take out the call to the service, which I need, I get no errors.

When I put the service in the app.controller() that already exists in the controller.js file and call it, I still get UNK Provider.  This makes ABSOLUTELY no sense.

[$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$injector/unpr?p0=URLProvider%20%3C-%20URL%20%3C-%20documentService

My personal website: [www.peterborreggine.us](http://www.peterborreggine.us), if you open the debug console and view: the Angular folder --> Controllers and Services, you'll see how I'm doing exactly what I am trying to accomplish here.

Of note, there are 65 module folders in the module directory all with their own controller.js and service.js.  But only one controller and one service per file is there.

Again, I've been using Angular since its inception and now on Angular 12. This telecom company needs to upgrade to at least Angular 12

UPDATE:

I just tried this with the same UNK Provider error and this is suggested in Angular's error above! I combined both the service and controller and STILL the same error

```
// Combined Service and then my Controller
app.service('documentService', ["$http", "URL", ($http, URL) => {
    let getDocuments = function () {
        return $http.get(URL)
            .success(function (data) {
                console.log('SUCCESS: Documents retreived', data);
                return data;
            })
            .error(function (e) {
                console.log(`He's dead Jim!`, e);
                return e;
            })
    }
    return ({
        getDocunment: getDocuments
    });
}]).controller("documentController", ["$scope", "documentService", ($scope, documentService) => {

    let docCtrl = $scope;
    //docCtrl = 'Hello World!';
    docCtrl.docContent = [];
    console.log('DOC CONTROL: ', docCtrl.content);

    docCtrl.fetchDocs = function () {
      documentService.getDocuments().then(function (result) {
        docCtrl.docContent = result.data;
        console.log('DOCS RETRIEVED: ', docCtrl.docContent);
      });
    }
    docCtrl.fetchDocs();
}]);
```

Comment: Please edit your question's subject so it focused more on the problem than angular versions.

Comment: Thanks, Marcin, better?